# Kubernetes Helm Chart Won't Update

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Delete the cached archive to force a redownload:

```
rm -rf ~/.helm/cache/archive/cp-helm-charts-0.1.0.tgz
```

Do an explicit repo update

```
helm repo update
```

Do a debug/dry-run install to force a download:

```
helm install --debug --dry-run confluent/cp-helm-charts > /dev/null
```

Look at the specific file in the .tgz archive where I want to see the fix:

```
tar xfO ~/.helm/cache/archive/cp-helm-charts-0.1.0.tgz cp-helm-charts/charts/cp-kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml | grep -n -C10 volumes:
```

Compare to the latest version on github, which was modified 8 days ago:
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml#L140

The github version has `- name: datadir-0`. The version Helm pulls just has `- name: datadir` without the trailing `-0`.

Why does the `.tgz` file that Helm pulls not have the latest fix in the master branch version on github? How do I fix this?

FYI, my relevant environment information:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.2", GitCommit:"7d2b0c73d734f6586ed222a567c5d103fed435be", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.2", GitCommit:"7d2b0c73d734f6586ed222a567c5d103fed435be", GitTreeState:"clean"}

helm repo list
NAME        URL                                             
stable      https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
local       http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts                    
confluent   https://confluentinc.github.io/cp-helm-charts/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart maintainer is distributing a .tgz chart that is not up to date with recent git commits. They recommend you build your own chart .tgz.